# I am having 2 workbooks and I need to copy the columns from one workbook to another based on matching values

Tags: vba, excel

I am having 2 workbooks and I need to copy the columns from one workbook to another based on matching values of another column that is similar in both workbooks.I am not able to apply lookup or any other solution, Kindly help me with the vba code of above problem.

Comment: Post the code you've written so far, so that we can provide help.

Comment: I have tried to write but it's not working so kindly help me with logic and code.

Comment: Can you at least add an example of what you have and what you want (with dummy data, if it is private)? At this point the question is unclear to say the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell from your question you want to have duplicate values from one workbook to another. What I would suggest is the below code attached to a button. The below code would match each column from A to I in this example. It is a lot less heavy on the resources but you will need extra code if you want dates not in american order.

```
Sub NewButton()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet 1")
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("File Directory of second workbook")
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet 1")

   ws.Range("A:I") = ws2.Range("A:I").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: I need to copy the value based on matched of another cell values so kindly do the modifications

Comment: all this instead of the 9 lines of code `ws.Range("A:I") = ws2.Range("A:I").Value`

Comment: You are going to need to provide a lot more information then as what I offered was a guess from what little you mentioned. Provide details of your code and we can take a look.